# Automate Flow Error

Tags: workflow

I know its wrong, I just don't know why.

I have a library of images. I am trying to create a flow that will place the same content that auto-populates into the 'Name' column, when an image is uploaded, into the default 'Title' column as well.

I want to create a calculated column based on extracted components of the image name in 'Name', however, by SP default I cannot see the column 'Name' as an option when creating a calculated column; however, I can see the column 'Title'; however, however no data auto-populates into 'Title'; hence the need for the flow. I hope that's clear enough. :-)

note: The 'UploadedCerts&Quals' is not a "List" but a Document Library, if that matters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following updates document [Title] with the file name without extension.
If you need to keep the extension, just update [Title] with varFileName, which has been initialized with **FileNameWithExtension** from the Dynamic content.

To remove file extension:

```
substring(variables('varFileName'), 0, indexOf(variables('varFileName'),'.'))
```

[image]

[image]

### Updating this post to populate [Title] from File Name for existing records

Steps:

1. Get all properties of existing files with **null** or **empty** [Title]
2. Add a **Compose** action to verify the number of files with empty [Title]. This is not required though
3. Update each file's [Title] property by using a [Apply to each] action by adding within it a [Set variable] and a [Update item] actions as shown in the screenshots below.

[image]

**Expression 1**

(type length() first in the expression window and then select [value] list of items from the Dynamic content)

```
 length(outputs('Get_files_(properties_only)')?['body/value'])
```

### Detail 1

[image]

### Expression 2, 3, & 4

```
2) FilenameWithExtension - from Dynamic content
items('Apply_to_each')?['{FilenameWithExtension}']

3) [ID] - from Dynamic content

items('Apply_to_each')?['ID']

4) Extract [Title] from varFileName. Expression window 

substring(variables('varFileName'), 0, indexOf(variables('varFileName'),'.'))
```

Comment: I made the changes and got the following error: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Update_item' inputs at line '1' and column '2932': 'The template language function 'substring' parameter is out of range: 'start index' must be non-negative integer and should be less than the length of the string.

Comment: What is in the [Name] of the file. Do you have a dot (.) in your file name? Instead of using the expression substring(..), first use the variable varFileName to see if the [Title] gets populated. When you look into the history of the flow execution, you can see the values of varFileName, can you post that for me?

Comment: My apology; yes, it working. If I add a file the 'Name' now also populates into 'Title'. This only works for 'newly created or changed files. Is there a way to initiate this action on the files that I've already uploaded (2,700 of them)? Or, do I have to reload each file in order to get the Name into the Title with the flow?

Comment: You don't have to do that. You create a separate flow and run it manually once to update [Title] for each file. Basically, the same thing, but: 1) need to retrieve all files properties 2) loop through each one and then update it. If you need help, I can update my post for that

Comment: Oh yes, please!!!!! Without your help I'll be here all day trying to figure out what comma or parenthesis goes where. If you could provide ANY assistance in this regard I would be grateful.

Comment: Updated my original post. This is the same thing but doing for each file using a loop. First ,test up-to **Compose** to see how many files are with empty [Title]. Once that is verified, proceed with the subsequent steps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I built to and tested to 'Compose' as instructed. The action returned "Inputs: 100; Outputs: 100". Is this what you expected? There are more than 2000 file names in the library that need updating through this flow.

Comment: Yes, there's a limit on [Get files (properties only)], and it seems 100 items at a time. So, you need to schedule this flow to run automatically multiple times or you could run manually 20+ times to process 2K items. I wanted you to check if getting properties of the files is working first. Since it's working now, you can move to the next steps and see how it works.

Comment: So, how do I add a step that will 'force' the flow to run the number of times necessary to go through the library once, and update all the files? After that I can delete this flow; another flow will do this for new updates.

Comment: Disregard; I deleted the manual start and added a Recurrence at the top. Its piecemeal but it seems to be working.

Comment: Good! was about to tell you that.